# Create tar archive without repetitive root name

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a tar archive with *tarfile* module in Python. All ok, but I get a gzip file named *archive.gz* which containa an archive named *archive.gz* too. How can I make the archive without repetitive name?

here the code:

```
import tarfile
import os

src_archive = 'C:\\source_archive'
dest_archive = 'C:\\archive.tar.gz'


def make_tarfile(output_filename, source_dir):
    with tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz") as tar:
        tar.add(source_dir, arcname=os.path.basename(source_dir))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('creating archive')
    make_tarfile(dest_archive,src_archive)
```

Comment: Or maybe I've misunderstood the output format: isn't "archive.tar.gz\archive.tar\"  correct since it is a tar that is gzipped. So the path looks ok, right?

Comment: If you  use `tar -xf tarfile.tar.gz` it will extract directly, rather than create a directory containing a .tar file. There is nothing wrong with your archive file. Presumably you used 7zip or winrar to extract?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, what I did was use UUID to randomly generate a string and append that to the end of the file (which requires a unique name)

Another thing you could do is use a database, and append name by index number.

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:15) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import uuid
>>> src_archive = f'C:\\source_archive-{str(uuid.uuid4()).split("-")[0]}'
>>> print(src_archive)
C:\source_archive-674fce6b
```